# WooCommerce Sidebar Active Tabs CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce Wordpress plugin for my site. On my products page I have the standard 'accordion' style layout that shows all sub-headers for the current category but hides all the sub-headers for 'non-active' categories

I would like to change the styling of the active categories but leave the non active tabs exactly the same. The issue is that any change seems to affect everything. I am using the flowing css

```
.cat-item cat-item-17 current-cat cat-parent {
    color: #20dbfc!;
}
```

you can see the site here - http://www.lukeallen.co/sites/wp-test-01/product-category/indoor-led-lighting/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply your custom rules to the current cat class only. You have included too many classes, and therefore have lost specificity.

Try:

```
.current-cat {
    color: #20dbfc!;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply unfortunately that still didn't work. There seems to be some sort of overriding css.

Would it matter that its nested in a list? I have attached an example of the html code below:

<ul class="product-categories">

<li class="cat-item cat-item-76"><a href="http://www.lukeallen.co/sites/wp-test-01/product-category/specials/">Specials</a></li>

<li class="cat-item cat-item-17 current-cat"><a href="http://www.lukeallen.co/sites/wp-test-01/product-category/indoor-led-lighting/">Indoor LED Lighting</a><ul class="children">

…

</ul>

Comment: @Roksalt From the look of that, you'll have to apply it to the a element, eg .current-cat a {
    color: #20dbfc!;
}

Comment: @Roksalt Also, just noticed theres an exclamation at the end of your color code, you should get rid of that.

Comment: Awesome applying that directly to the element worked perfectly. Thanks so much @TalkNerdyToMe